# Getting a 500 internal server error for my python script, unsure what the issue is

Tags: python, html, cgi

below is a python script that is made to open a .ssv file (space separated vector) and generate a survey page based on the contents of the .ssv file. the file contains the survey name as well as questions to be asked in the survey. as part of our assignment, each group member is supposed to host this script (called survey.py). however, when I attempt to run survey.py on my page, i get a 500 internal server error. looking at the error log, it says "Premature end of script headers: survey.py" I am unsure what this means, can anyone help?

Here is the code:

```
     #!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

new = open("survey.ssv", "r")
lines = new.readlines()
i = 0

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Take-a-Survey!</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body bgcolor='white' text='black'>"
print "<center>"
print "<h1>Take Survey Page</h>"
print "</center>"
print "Information."
print "<br><br>"
for line in lines:
    if i == 0:
            print "Survey Title:<br>%s" % line
        print "<br><br>"
            print '<form action="results.py" method="post">'
    else:
            print "Question %d:<br>%s" % (i, line)
            print '<br>'
        print '<input type="radio" value="stronglyAgree" name="demFeels%d"></input>' % i
        print 'Strongly agree'
        print '<br>'
        print '<input type="radio" value="agree" name="demFeels%d"></input>' % i
        print 'Agree'
        print '<br>'
        print '<input type="radio" value="disagree" name="demFeels%d"></input>' % i
        print 'Disagree'
        print '<br>'
        print '<input type="radio" value="stronglyDisagree" name="demFeels%d"></input>' % i
        print 'Strongly disagree'
        print '<br><br>'
    i = i + 1
print '<input type="submit" name="results" value="Submit">'
print '</form>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
new.close()
print '</form>'
```

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place; make sure you don't mix tabs and spaces.

Comment: what do you mean by all over the place? as in the tabbing style is inconsistent? I was under the impression that it was correct, but I am the one with the query, haha

Comment: Look at the lines below `if i == 0:`. The indentation on the `print` lines is *not* consistent. But if you edit the question then it looks lined up. This is directly caused by mixing tabs and spaces for indentation. Run `python -tt yourscript.py` and correct all errors that it finds. Then configure your text editor to only use spaces for indentation.

Comment: in my gedit window however the indentations are indeed consistent, its only when i wrote it in the text box on this site that the indentation appears inconsistent. also, when writing the code i only used the tab button for indentation.

Comment: You'll still need to fix your tabs.

Comment: ok, thank you for staying and helping out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just after the Content type header line add:

```
print                               # blank line, end of headers
```

You need to properly signal that you ended printing headers by this empty line.